# What do I do about "Use of uninitialized value" warnings?

Tags: perl

I have some mistakes in my code. This code works locally but not on my server.

```
#Vérification de la concordance BD ->  Sons
for (my $k = 0; $k < scalar(@tableau_de_donnees); $k++) {
    my $donnee = $tableau_de_donnees[$k];
    if ($donnee) {
        my @une_donnee = split(/\./, $donnee);    #enlève l'extension
        for (my $l = 0; $l < scalar(@tableau_de_sons); $l++) {
            my $son    = $tableau_de_donnees[$l];
            my @un_son = split(/\./, $son);       #enlève l'extension
            if ($une_donnee[0] eq ($un_son[0])) {
                $trouver_son = "1";
            }
        }
        if ($trouver_son == "0") {
            print "Le fichier "
              . $tableau_de_donnees[$k]
              . " est introuvable. \n";
        }
        $trouver_son = "0";
    } else {
        print "Fin";
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

> Use of uninitialized value in string eq at verif_db_physio.pl line 141,  line 2.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $son in split at verif_db_physio.pl line 139,  line 2.

Comment: Can you mark the lines from the error messages in your code (in English)? What is your code supposed to do? How does the input `@tableau_de_donnees` look like?

Comment: I'd bet the data is different on each server. There isn't a way to answer this question without more information.

Comment: En passant, `if ($trouver_son == "0")` devrait être `if ($trouver_son == 0)` ou simplement `if (!$trouver_son)`. Mais ce n'est pas la réponse à ta question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like this:

```
my $son    = $tableau_de_donnees[$l];
```

should be this::

```
my $son    = $tableau_de_sons[$l];
```

You could avoid the problem entirely by changing

```
for (my $l = 0; $l < scalar(@tableau_de_sons); $l++) {
    my $son    = $tableau_de_donnees[$l];
```

to

```
for my $son (@tableau_de_sons) {
```